# How to quickly check the value of bash variables, aliases and history commands from terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, history

How do you expand in place:

- bash aliases
- environment variables
- history commands

to edit them and check they are correct?

For example, I have some aliases I use for flashing different devices and I just wanted to change the revision number to install, I don't really want to copy/paste from my `.bashrc` to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` offers the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> shortcut (from the `bash` man page):

> ```
>    shell-expand-line (M-C-e)
>           Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and
>           history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions.
> ```

Examples:

- `ls` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

  ```
  ls -aF --color
  ```
- `!268` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

  ```
  ps -aef
  ```
- `$PATH` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

  ```
  /opt/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
  ```